# Erro quando tento buscar de um formulário HTML informação do BD MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou tentando fazer uma busca através de informações passadas pelo usuário. Porem, quando clico em enviar, dá um erro.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o meu código do Formulário e o do PHP.

1)HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Busca da Pessoa Ideal</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form" action="inserir.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="buscar">
            <h1>Características do seu par ideal</h1>

            <table style="margin-top: 15px" cellspacing="10">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select name="peso">
                            <option>Peso:</option>
                            <option value="menor_40">Menor que 40kg</option>
                            <option value="entre_40_50">Maior que 40kg e menor que 50kg</option>
                            <option value="entre_50_60">Maior que 50kg e menor que 60kg</option>
                            <option value="entre_60_70">Maior que 60kg e menor que 70kg</option>
                            <option value="maior_70">Maior que 70kg</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select name="altura">
                            <option>Tamanho:</option>
                            <option value="menor_14">Menor que 1.40cm</option>
                            <option value="entre_14_15">Maior que 1.40cm e menor que 1.50cm</option>
                            <option value="entre_15_16">Maior que 1.50cm e menor que 1.60cm</option>
                            <option value="entre_16_17">Maior que 1.60cm e menor que 1.70cm</option>
                            <option value="entre_17_18">Maior que 1.70cm e menor que 1.80cm</option>
                            <option value="maior_18">Maior que 1.80cm</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cor do cabelo: <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="corCabelo" value="preto">Preto
                        <input type="radio" name="corCabelo" value="loiro">Loiro
                        <input type="radio" name="corCabelo" value="ruivo">Ruivo
                        <input type="radio" name="corCabelo" value="outros">Outros
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sexo: <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="M">Masculino
                        <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="F">Feminino
                    <td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        <button type="reset">Apagar</button>
                        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

2)PHP

```
    <?php
error_reporting (E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE & ~ E_DEPRECATED);
$host  = "localhost";
$user  = "root";
$pass  = "";
$banco = "relacionamentos";

//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($_POST);
//echo "</pre>";
//exit;

$conexao = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($banco) or die (mysql_error());

if($_POST['tipo'] == 'cadastro')
{
    $inserir = "insert into cadastro(nome,rua,cidade,estado,idade,peso,tamanho,nacionalidade,cabelo,sexo) values ('$_POST[nome]','$_POST[rua]','$_POST[cidade]','$_POST[estado]','$_POST[idade]','$_POST[peso]'"
        . ",'$_POST[tamanho]','$_POST[nacionalidade]','$_POST[corCabelo]','$_POST[sexo]')";

//$inserir = "insert into cadastro(nome,rua,cidade,estado) values ('$_POST[nome]','$_POST[rua]','$_POST[cidade]',"
  //      . "'$_POST[estado]','$_POST[idade]','$_POST[peso]','$_POST[tamanho]','$_POST[nacionalidade]',"
    //    . "'$_POST[corCabelo]','$_POST[sexo]')";

    if (mysql_query($inserir)) {
        echo "Dados inseridos com sucesso!";
    }
}
elseif($_POST['tipo'] == 'buscar')
{
    $peso   = get_peso($_POST['peso']);
    $altura = get_altura($_POST['altura']);
    $cabelo = "cabelo = " . $_POST['corCabelo'];
    $sexo   = "sexo = " . $_POST['sexo'];

    $select = mysql_query("select * from cadastro where $peso and $altura and $cabelo and $sexo");

    $array_busca = array();

    while($ln = mysql_fetch_assoc($select))
    {
        $array_busca[] = $ln;
    }

    if(!empty($array_busca))
    {
        foreach($array_busca as $pessoa)
        {
            ?>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $pessoa['nome']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pessoa['idade']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pessoa['cidade'] . "/" . $pessoa['estado']?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <?php
        }
    }
}

function get_peso($peso)
{
    switch ($peso)
    {
        case 'menor_40':    return 'peso <= 40';
        case 'entre_40_50': return 'peso >=40 and peso <= 50';
    }
}

function get_altura($altura)
{
    switch ($altura)
    {
        case 'menor_14':    return 'tamanho <= 1.4';
        case 'entre_14_15': return 'tamanho >=1.4 and tamanho <= 1.5';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: 1º verifique a sua connexao se funciona;
2º coloque no lugar de `mysql`, `mysqli`

Comment: Então, a conexão deve estar funcionando, já que consigo cadastrar no BD.

Comment: E é para alterar em todas as partes onde tem mysql e coloco mysqli?

Comment: sim, experimente com mysqli, dependendo da versão do seu php isso pode influenciar.

Comment: Tentei e continua com erro =(

Comment: Não basta substituir `mysql` por `mysqli` nos códigos. A forma de fazer isso é um pouco diferente, o que o @djva quis dizer é que a função `mysql_` já está obsoleta, então migre para o `mysqli` que seria o mysql _improved_. Na versão 7 do _PHP_ a função `mysql_` não funciona mais. [Porque não devemos mais usar funções do tipo mysql_](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Alter
ei um bocado o seu código, no entanto deveria colocar a ligação à BD em uma outra pagina ou então utilizar orientação a objectos.

EDIT: Veja se assim funciona. Alterei a conexão

```
  <?php

 $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'relacionamentos') 
                                                                    or die ('Cannot connect to db');


    if($_POST['tipo'] == 'cadastro')
    {
        $inserir = "insert into cadastro(nome,rua,cidade,estado,idade,peso,tamanho,nacionalidade,cabelo,sexo) values ('$_POST[nome]','$_POST[rua]','$_POST[cidade]','$_POST[estado]','$_POST[idade]','$_POST[peso]'"
            . ",'$_POST[tamanho]','$_POST[nacionalidade]','$_POST[corCabelo]','$_POST[sexo]')";


        if (mysqli_query($conn, $inserir)) {
            echo "Dados inseridos com sucesso!";
        }
    }
    elseif($_POST['tipo'] == 'buscar')
    {
        $peso   = get_peso($_POST['peso']);
        $altura = get_altura($_POST['altura']);
        $cabelo = "cabelo = " . $_POST['corCabelo'];
        $sexo   = "sexo = " . $_POST['sexo'];    

    $select = mysqli_query("select * from cadastro where $peso and $altura and $cabelo and $sexo");
            while($pessoa= mysqli_fetch_array($select))
            {
               echo" <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>" .$pessoa['nome']."</td>
                            <td>".$pessoa['idade'] ."</td>
                            <td>". $pessoa['cidade'] . "/" . $pessoa['estado'] . "</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>";


             }
        }


    function get_peso($peso)
    {
        switch ($peso)
        {
            case 'menor_40':    return 'peso <= 40';
            case 'entre_40_50': return 'peso >=40 and peso <= 50';
        }
    }

    function get_altura($altura)
    {
        switch ($altura)
        {
            case 'menor_14':    return 'tamanho <= 1.4';
            case 'entre_14_15': return 'tamanho >=1.4 and tamanho <= 1.5';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Quando vou inserir, dá erro de sintaxe.

Comment: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\wamp\www\Relacionamento\inserir.php on line 52

Comment: No elseif, a ultima chave está sobrando. Mas se apagar, dá outro erro.

Comment: ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\Relacionamento\inserir.php on line 14
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0000 262792 {main}( ) ..\inserir.php:0
2 0.0156 272440 mysqli_select_db ( ) ..\inserir.php:14

( ! ) Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\wamp\www\Relacionamento\inserir.php on line 14
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0000 262792 {main}( ) ..\inserir.php:0
2 0.0176 272920 mysqli_error ( ) ..\inserir.php:14

Comment: eu só alterei a partir do select, no entanto eu perguntei se a connexão esta bem feita. Tente corrigir e leia o erro que ele aponta para a linha 14.Se não sabe inglês veja no tradutor.

O erro que ai dá e exatamente na sua conexão

Comment: Fiz umas alterações, veja agora se já funciona.

Comment: ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\Relacionamento\inserir.php on line 27

Comment: ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp\www\Relacionamento\inserir.php on line 28

Comment: Dá esses dois erros. Obrigado mesmo pela paciencia. Até eu já perdi kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: Retirei 2 erros que tinha o código, se não der, veja se é alguma coisa do seu lado, não dependa só dos outros para fazer os trabalhos.